# How to add or subtract dates, days,months in bootstrap datetime widget?

Tags: javascript, datetime, twitter-bootstrap, datejs

I am using a Bootstrap DateTime widget in my template, I have placed 2 widgets (From, To) side by side to select a particular range of dates, hours, or months according to need. I have linked both widgets, so that user may always choose the "To" range lesser than "From". For that purpose I have added or subtracted the dates by numbers like:

```
        var evDate = ev.date;
        if (evDate != null) {
            $('.'+reportCategoryTo.id).
                        datetimepicker('setStartDate', evDate);
            var evDateObject = new Date(evDate.valueOf());
            var reportDateTimeCategoryFrom = report_date_time_category[0][0];
            var reportDateTimeCategoryTo = report_date_time_category[1][0];
            if (reportDateTimeCategoryFrom.category.indexOf("Daily") !== -1) {
                var newDate = evDateObject.setDate(evDateObject.getDate() + 31);
            }
            else if (reportDateTimeCategoryFrom.category.indexOf("Monthly") !== -1) {
                var newDate = evDateObject.setDate(evDateObject.getDate() + 365);
            }
            else {
                var newDate = evDateObject.setDate(evDateObject.getHours() + 24);
            }

            var newDateObject = new Date(newDate);
            $('.'+reportCategoryTo.id).
                        datetimepicker('setEndDate', newDateObject);
            }
        else {
            console.log('The change is null',evDate);
            $('.'+reportCategoryTo.id).
                            datetimepicker('setStartDate', null);
            $('.'+reportCategoryTo.id).
                            datetimepicker('setEndDate', null);
            }
        });
```

This does'nt show the range when user chooses like 30th of may or something similar.
I then Found `Datejs` which helps in adding or subtracting dates and etc. I used Datejs like this:

```
            if (reportDateTimeCategoryFrom.category.indexOf("Daily") !== -1) {
                var newDate = evDateObject.setDate(evDateObject.getDate().add(31).days());
            }
            else if (reportDateTimeCategoryFrom.category.indexOf("Monthly") !== -1) {
                var newDate = evDateObject.setDate(evDateObject.getDate().add(365));
            }
            else {
                var newDate = evDateObject.setDate(evDateObject.getHours().addHours(24));
```

But my console prompts this error:

```
TypeError: evDateObject.getDate(...).add is not a function
```

I have Imported the `date.js` file but even then this is'nt working. Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datejs is abandoned, I wouldn't recommend using it.  [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).

You might want to consider [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which also has functions for datetime arithmetic.

For example:

```
var m = moment(evDateObject.getDate());
m.add('months', 1);
evDateObject.setDate(m.toDate());
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to worry this much about the feature you want to implement, its pretty simple if you could use jQuery UI. Use below example and jQuery library will take care of your need

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form id="process_form" class="form" action="process.php" method="POST">
<label for="DOA">From:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtDOA" name="txtDOA" required="" class="hasDatepicker">
<label for="DOD">To:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtDOD" name="txtDOD" required="" class="hasDatepicker">
</form>

$(function()
  { 
        $("#txtDOA").datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          onClose: function( selectedDate ) { $( "#txtDOD" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate ); }
        });
        $("#txtDOD").datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          onClose: function( selectedDate ) { $("#txtDOA").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate ); }
        });   
  });
```